# How to detect new Machine like Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

I am actually trying to detect a person, using a computer, Just like facebook. Whenever you sign into facebook using different machine, it detects the new machine and asks you the register it. How do they find out that the person is using another computer. May be they can track the clients MAC or actual IP (but this normally changes upon every reconnection).

How to detect this?

Comment: I think Facebook is doing something with IP addresses. Because if you failed to identify the persons in the pictures, the next time you successfully login from a known location, you get message from which *country* the failed login was.

Comment: @Felix Kling, How do they detect, the user is opening its website anonymously

Comment: @Felix Kling, Facebook asks to identity person, if it cannot correctly locate, from where the user is trying to access the website (which is when they browse the website anonymously, through websites like www.hidemyass.com). How do they detect this?

Answer (score 15):

I recently tried this myself with the following results:

---

MACBOOK = My laptop

DELL = My friends laptop

I logged in to Facebook on MACBOOK in SWEDEN, and was **asked to name the device**.

My friend logged in to Facebook on DELL in SWEDEN and was **asked to name the device**.

We both went to JAPAN.

I logged in to Facebook on MACBOOK in JAPAN, I was *not requested to name the device again*.

My friend logged in to Facebook on DELL in JAPAN, and was *not requested to name the device again*.

I logged in to Facebook on DELL in JAPAN, and was **asked to name the device.**

---

So, from that I conclude two different options:

1. A persistant cookie for each Facebook user that logins on the device.
2. Somehow Facebook can match MAC-adresses.

Since 2. is never achievable without you installing plugins or whatnot, we are left with 1.

Exploring the cookies I have with Facebook, I discover 13 of them. Using Google Chrome for this is really useful. Just go to chrome://settings/cookies and you'll get a list.

The Facebook cookie named "lu" contains the following information:

```
Name:   lu
Content:    (data)
Domain: .facebook.com
Path:   /
Send For:   Any kind of connection
Accessible to Script:   No (HttpOnly)
Created:    Thursday, June 9, 2011 8:58:10 PM
Expires:    Saturday, June 8, 2013 8:58:10 PM
```

This is the only cookie they have that don't expire on browser close, the same day or a few days ahead. My educated guess would be that (data) would consist of the device information they check for this feature.

I would also guess that they store the information in their database, and upon logging in they match the data against you again. If you match in certain predefined ways (like, both the ip adress and the browser is still the same), you automatically gets approved. This would explain why you could format your computer and still have the device approved.

I am guessing that if you delete all cookies and then move to a different internet provider, you would be required to register the device again.

Comment: for tracking use a good mixture of browser user agent, cookie and ip, that is enough to accurately track a user, and when one piece of data changes, its easy to know

Comment: same conclusion was mine but i thinks that that they also save region in which maximum logins are done because if you clear all histories and cookies even after that it doesn't ask me to save the new browser(may be they do it automatically)

Answer (score 5):

This process has very little to do with cookies, it's called fingerprinting.

Basically, you can look at the functionality and support of your browser and there is a likelihood that the combination will be somewhat unique.

You can test this out here: https://panopticlick.eff.org

JavaScript example, but the theory can be transposed to any language: 
http://valve.github.io/fingerprintjs2/

Using this in combination with cookies is the best way to detect unique devices. Store the fingerprint in a hidden field when you login and check that against the available fingerprints you've already got.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what does facebook do but I suppose they check a cookie.
To be sure, you can setup some HTTP proxy like Fiddler and watch all HTTP headers being sent.

No, MAC address isn't accessible over internet and IP is not the same thing as "Machine"

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is cookies plus IP address.

However, as you say, IP addresses can change and cookies can be cleared by the user.

There are in fact a whole load of ways to determine information about a user's machine, ranging from the browser ID to detecting the list of fonts installed on the computer. A recent experiment managed to show that without using cookies, it was possible for them to detect unique computers with quite a good degree of accuracy.

However, it's highly unlikely that you'd need to do all of that -- most sites that do this just use cookies, and live with the fact that they can be reset. After all, if the user has cleared their cookies, they are expecting sites to forget who they are.

Also, pretty much any technique you use to identify people will be perceieved as an invasion of the user's privacy (even cookies have this image for many people, because of abuse by advertising companies, hence why browsers allow them to be cleared).

Comment: You said `A recent experiment managed to show that without using cookies, it was possible for them to detect unique computers` can you tell me more about it

Comment: @mrNepal: see http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/EFF-demonstrates-a-browser-s-finger-print-918786.html and http://www.eff.org/press/archives/2010/05/13

Comment: @mrNepal - yep, VolkerK has the one. I still wouldn't suggest going overboard with this sort of thing unless it's utterly critical. Even then, you'll never get absolute certainty.

Comment: I dont think facebook uses cookies and ip addresses, because even after reinstalling the OS and changing the ISP, it didn't ask be to register the machine.....

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses cookies to detect new devices. Deleting all cookies will lead Facebook to ask you to name your new device. Facebook has some tolerance for deleted cookies. For instance, deleting the long-living cookies has no effect if session cookies are set and you are already logged in.

In addition Facebook seems to use the IP to detect when the user logs in far away from their usual location.

Answer (score 1):

I checked my facebook cookies and (contrary to @Mattis) i found a cookie called c_user, i think that is the actual cookie that holds your id in a 15 digit decimal number, also another persistent cookie called datr that stores a 21 digit string with _ at the end

I hope i helped

Comment: Hi @stealth9799! I wrote my answer in 2011, things might have changed quite a bit since. Way to go keeping the post updated :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if facebook uses this method, but an obvious method is simply testing for a cookie and setting it if it isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

facebook may detect machine by OS and copmuter name

to get remote machine computer name :

[Get Client Machine Name in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142051/get-client-machine-name-in-php)

to get remote machine OS :

[Get operating system info with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070154/get-operating-system-info-with-php)

Comment: but many   users use windows and chrome on it  now how you differentiate.
And many computers may have same names and the name  is not always accecible