# Login with new device prompt in PHP

Tags: php, user-agent

When you login to facebook on a new device, they prompt you to name the device. How are they detecting new devices? Are they simply storing the `user agents` for each account, or is there a better way to do this? I want to implement this functionality in my `php` application.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830037/how-to-detect-new-machine-like-facebook

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty mundane:
Store a unique id in a cookie in the browser the first time you encounter it. No cookie == new browser.

Comment: Ahh interesting. Do you know for a fact that is how Facebook does it vs using the user agent?

Comment: The user agent string is in no way unique to a machine. Nobody in their right mind would use it for that purpose. :) And no, I do not know this 100% irrefutably for a fact, but they are setting a bunch of opaque cookies on your machine and it's the easiest and most reliable method, so it's perfectly plausible.

Comment: So I get to name the cookie something like `my-app-name-device`, but what should the value be? Basically aren't I simply checking if the cookie exists? Do I care what the value is?

Comment: Also, not sure Facebook is simply doing a cookie, because I fired up safari and cleared my cookies, and it did not ask me to add the device. Probably because I already added the computer in Chrome.

Comment: The value of the cookie doesn't matter, it should simply be a *random, unique value*, which you can store in your database to uniquely identify the machine. They are *probably* using a persistent cookie, which tries to store the value in any nook and cranny it can find, including Flash cookies, local storage etc. Stackoverflow does the same, try deleting your cookies here and see yourself magically be logged in anyway.