# Get operating system info

Tags: php, operating-system, user-agent

I recently started wondering about sites like http://thismachine.info/ that get the user's operating system info. I have not been able to find out how to do that with PHP, and wanted to try to figure it out.

I noticed that they list the `user-agent`, which gives lots of info about the browser. Do they get the operating system information from that, or from something else? Is there an API I could use to get the user's operating system?

I see how they got the Browser and IP, but could not figure out the Operating System part!

Comment: As [**Amal Murali**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18070175/1415724) stated in his answer below, `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` will show (to a certain extent) the user's operating system. For me, it detected `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0`, where I am in fact using Windows XP, so it's not an exact science.

Comment: As to how `http://thismachine.info/` knows I'm using Windows XP? That I don't know, however they must be using a script that will find and replace then echo it afterwards. To my knowledge, there is nothing that will determine the exact operating system, as I see this would fall under the securities domain.

Comment: I answered my own question. If you visit this answer on SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/15497878/1415724 you will notice how they echo `Windows XP` from the array `/windows nt 5.1/i'     =>  'Windows XP',`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Because Windows XP's internal version number is 5.1. Wikipedia will tell you the internal version of all Windows releases.

Comment: PS: Windows Vista = 6.0, Windows 7 = 6.1, Windows 8 = 6.2, Windows 8.1 = 6.3, Windows 10 = 10.0. For a full list (and future Windows releases) see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724832%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Well, a brief distinction between getting `http-user-agent` and `device info` like `OS`, `Device type` etc.: you can't accurately do that from http headers. Even if you did, the list of browsers, devices and OS keeps changing making the solution partially (in worst case, completely) obsolete. Even the well known libraries out there will always be `<100%` reliable. Why and how you use the information should help you decide whether you want something like `if(stripos($user_agent, "win") !== false){/*windows*/}` or more detailed and strict checks in the libraries.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

The code below could explain in its own right, how http://thismachine.info/ is able to show which operating system someone is using.

What it does is that, it sniffs your core operating system model, for example `windows nt 5.1` as my own.

It then passes windows nt 5.1/i  to Windows XP as the operating system.

Using: `'/windows nt 5.1/i' => 'Windows XP',` from an array.

You could say guesswork, or an approximation yet nonetheless pretty much bang on.

Borrowed from an answer on SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/15497878/

```
<?php

$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

function getOS() { 

    global $user_agent;

    $os_platform  = "Unknown OS Platform";

    $os_array     = array(
                          '/windows nt 10/i'      =>  'Windows 10',
                          '/windows nt 6.3/i'     =>  'Windows 8.1',
                          '/windows nt 6.2/i'     =>  'Windows 8',
                          '/windows nt 6.1/i'     =>  'Windows 7',
                          '/windows nt 6.0/i'     =>  'Windows Vista',
                          '/windows nt 5.2/i'     =>  'Windows Server 2003/XP x64',
                          '/windows nt 5.1/i'     =>  'Windows XP',
                          '/windows xp/i'         =>  'Windows XP',
                          '/windows nt 5.0/i'     =>  'Windows 2000',
                          '/windows me/i'         =>  'Windows ME',
                          '/win98/i'              =>  'Windows 98',
                          '/win95/i'              =>  'Windows 95',
                          '/win16/i'              =>  'Windows 3.11',
                          '/macintosh|mac os x/i' =>  'Mac OS X',
                          '/mac_powerpc/i'        =>  'Mac OS 9',
                          '/linux/i'              =>  'Linux',
                          '/ubuntu/i'             =>  'Ubuntu',
                          '/iphone/i'             =>  'iPhone',
                          '/ipod/i'               =>  'iPod',
                          '/ipad/i'               =>  'iPad',
                          '/android/i'            =>  'Android',
                          '/blackberry/i'         =>  'BlackBerry',
                          '/webos/i'              =>  'Mobile'
                    );

    foreach ($os_array as $regex => $value)
        if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent))
            $os_platform = $value;

    return $os_platform;
}

function getBrowser() {

    global $user_agent;

    $browser        = "Unknown Browser";

    $browser_array = array(
                            '/msie/i'      => 'Internet Explorer',
                            '/firefox/i'   => 'Firefox',
                            '/safari/i'    => 'Safari',
                            '/chrome/i'    => 'Chrome',
                            '/edge/i'      => 'Edge',
                            '/opera/i'     => 'Opera',
                            '/netscape/i'  => 'Netscape',
                            '/maxthon/i'   => 'Maxthon',
                            '/konqueror/i' => 'Konqueror',
                            '/mobile/i'    => 'Handheld Browser'
                     );

    foreach ($browser_array as $regex => $value)
        if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent))
            $browser = $value;

    return $browser;
}


$user_os        = getOS();
$user_browser   = getBrowser();

$device_details = "<strong>Browser: </strong>".$user_browser."<br /><strong>Operating System: </strong>".$user_os."";

print_r($device_details);

echo("<br /><br /><br />".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."");

?>
```

---

Footnotes:
**(Jan. 19/14)** There was a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3842648) on Jan. 18, 2014 to add `/msie|trident/i` by [YJSoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3211589/yjsoft) a new member on SO.

The comment read as:

Comment: because msie11's ua doesn't include msie (it includes trident instead)

I researched this for a bit, and found a few links explaining the Trident string.

- http://www.sitepoint.com/ie11-smells-like-firefox/
- http://www.upsdell.ca/BrowserNews/res_sniff.htm
- [How can I target only Internet Explorer 11 with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17447373/)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_%28layout_engine%29
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17907562/1415724
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625(v=vs.110).aspx
- [An article on MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx)
- [An article on NCZOnline](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/03/27/internet-explorer-11s-user-agent-string-what-does-it-mean/)

Although the edit was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3842648) (not by myself, but by some of the other editors), it's worth reading up on the links above, and to use your proper judgement.

---

As per a question asked about detecting SUSE, have found this piece of code at the following URL:

- http://codes-sources.commentcamarche.net/source/49533-operating-system-detection

Additional code:

```
/* return Operating System */
function operating_system_detection(){
    if ( isset( $_SERVER ) ) {
        $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    }
    else {
        global $HTTP_SERVER_VARS;
        if ( isset( $HTTP_SERVER_VARS ) ) {
            $agent = $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        }
        else {
            global $HTTP_USER_AGENT;
            $agent = $HTTP_USER_AGENT;
        }
    }
    $ros[] = array('Windows XP', 'Windows XP');
    $ros[] = array('Windows NT 5.1|Windows NT5.1)', 'Windows XP');
    $ros[] = array('Windows 2000', 'Windows 2000');
    $ros[] = array('Windows NT 5.0', 'Windows 2000');
    $ros[] = array('Windows NT 4.0|WinNT4.0', 'Windows NT');
    $ros[] = array('Windows NT 5.2', 'Windows Server 2003');
    $ros[] = array('Windows NT 6.0', 'Windows Vista');
    $ros[] = array('Windows NT 7.0', 'Windows 7');
    $ros[] = array('Windows CE', 'Windows CE');
    $ros[] = array('(media center pc).([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2})', 'Windows Media Center');
    $ros[] = array('(win)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9x]{1,2})', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('(win)([0-9]{2})', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('(windows)([0-9x]{2})', 'Windows');
    // Doesn't seem like these are necessary...not totally sure though..
    //$ros[] = array('(winnt)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}', 'Windows NT');
    //$ros[] = array('(windows nt)(([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1})', 'Windows NT'); // fix by bg
    $ros[] = array('Windows ME', 'Windows ME');
    $ros[] = array('Win 9x 4.90', 'Windows ME');
    $ros[] = array('Windows 98|Win98', 'Windows 98');
    $ros[] = array('Windows 95', 'Windows 95');
    $ros[] = array('(windows)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2})', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('win32', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('(java)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2})', 'Java');
    $ros[] = array('(Solaris)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9x]{1,2}){0,1}', 'Solaris');
    $ros[] = array('dos x86', 'DOS');
    $ros[] = array('unix', 'Unix');
    $ros[] = array('Mac OS X', 'Mac OS X');
    $ros[] = array('Mac_PowerPC', 'Macintosh PowerPC');
    $ros[] = array('(mac|Macintosh)', 'Mac OS');
    $ros[] = array('(sunos)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}', 'SunOS');
    $ros[] = array('(beos)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}', 'BeOS');
    $ros[] = array('(risc os)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2})', 'RISC OS');
    $ros[] = array('os/2', 'OS/2');
    $ros[] = array('freebsd', 'FreeBSD');
    $ros[] = array('openbsd', 'OpenBSD');
    $ros[] = array('netbsd', 'NetBSD');
    $ros[] = array('irix', 'IRIX');
    $ros[] = array('plan9', 'Plan9');
    $ros[] = array('osf', 'OSF');
    $ros[] = array('aix', 'AIX');
    $ros[] = array('GNU Hurd', 'GNU Hurd');
    $ros[] = array('(fedora)', 'Linux - Fedora');
    $ros[] = array('(kubuntu)', 'Linux - Kubuntu');
    $ros[] = array('(ubuntu)', 'Linux - Ubuntu');
    $ros[] = array('(debian)', 'Linux - Debian');
    $ros[] = array('(CentOS)', 'Linux - CentOS');
    $ros[] = array('(Mandriva).([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?(\.[0-9]{1,3})?)', 'Linux - Mandriva');
    $ros[] = array('(SUSE).([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?(\.[0-9]{1,3})?)', 'Linux - SUSE');
    $ros[] = array('(Dropline)', 'Linux - Slackware (Dropline GNOME)');
    $ros[] = array('(ASPLinux)', 'Linux - ASPLinux');
    $ros[] = array('(Red Hat)', 'Linux - Red Hat');
    // Loads of Linux machines will be detected as unix.
    // Actually, all of the linux machines I've checked have the 'X11' in the User Agent.
    //$ros[] = array('X11', 'Unix');
    $ros[] = array('(linux)', 'Linux');
    $ros[] = array('(amigaos)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2})', 'AmigaOS');
    $ros[] = array('amiga-aweb', 'AmigaOS');
    $ros[] = array('amiga', 'Amiga');
    $ros[] = array('AvantGo', 'PalmOS');
    //$ros[] = array('(Linux)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}(rel\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}-([0-9]{1,2}) i([0-9]{1})86){1}', 'Linux');
    //$ros[] = array('(Linux)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}(rel\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1} i([0-9]{1}86)){1}', 'Linux');
    //$ros[] = array('(Linux)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}(rel\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1})', 'Linux');
    $ros[] = array('[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}', 'Linux');
    $ros[] = array('(webtv)/([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2})', 'WebTV');
    $ros[] = array('Dreamcast', 'Dreamcast OS');
    $ros[] = array('GetRight', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('go!zilla', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('gozilla', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('gulliver', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('ia archiver', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('NetPositive', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('mass downloader', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('microsoft', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('offline explorer', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('teleport', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('web downloader', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('webcapture', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('webcollage', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('webcopier', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('webstripper', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('webzip', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('wget', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('Java', 'Unknown');
    $ros[] = array('flashget', 'Windows');
    // delete next line if the script show not the right OS
    //$ros[] = array('(PHP)/([0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2})', 'PHP');
    $ros[] = array('MS FrontPage', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('(msproxy)/([0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2})', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('(msie)([0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2})', 'Windows');
    $ros[] = array('libwww-perl', 'Unix');
    $ros[] = array('UP.Browser', 'Windows CE');
    $ros[] = array('NetAnts', 'Windows');
    $file = count ( $ros );
    $os = '';
    for ( $n=0 ; $n<$file ; $n++ ){
        if ( preg_match('/'.$ros[$n][0].'/i' , $agent, $name)){
            $os = @$ros[$n][1].' '.@$name[2];
            break;
        }
    }
    return trim ( $os );
}
```

---

Edit: April 12, 2015

I noticed a question yesterday that could be relevant to this Q&A and may be helpful for some. In regards to:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; SAMSUNG-GT-I9505 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36`

- Question: [Store specific data in variable from another variable with regex with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29583963/)
- Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29584014/

---

**Another edit**, and adding a reference link that was asked (and answered/accepted today, Nov. 4/16) which may be of use.

Consult the Q&A here on Stack:

- [PHP Regex for OS detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427531/php-regex-for-os-detection)

Comment: What about Windows 8.1 ?

Comment: @HamedKamrava I'm sure that `'/windows nt 6.2/i'  =>  'Windows 8',` in the code will cover it.

Comment: No. My OS is Windows 8.1 but the result is `Operating System: Unknown OS Platform`

Comment: I found it. `'/windows nt 6.3/i'` is for Windows 8.1

Comment: Any idea about OS Mavericks? I get Unknown OS Platform.

Comment: I found a few links, some with relevant info. 
http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/firefox-history.html 

https://gist.github.com/erikng/7140045 

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20091228114759199 
It's worth noting that in OS X 10.9 Mavericks, Safari uses com.apple.Webkit.Networking as User Agent when requesting proxy auto configuration. This after Googling `"mavericks HTTP_USER_AGENT"` @ben_aaron

Comment: Any way to determine suse?

Comment: @DainisAbols Closest thing I could find was code found in this link http://codes-sources.commentcamarche.net/source/49533-operating-system-detection - If that provides a solution for you, please let me know and I will add it to my answer. Thanks for the question, *cheers* - P.s.: The page is in French, but the code is international language ;-)

Comment: @DainisAbols You're very much welcome. I've added it as an edit. Thanks again for your question. I hope all goes well with the production, *cheers*.

Comment: I honestly don't know why the answer's getting downvoted. At the very least give an explanation as to why that is and if it can be further improved. How, I've no idea; only "you" know that.

Comment: add this to detect Chrome Operating Systems: `'/cros/i'  =>  'Chrome OS'`

Comment: Just like "bad publicity", it's still "publicity". So thanks for the vote :)

Comment: `http://thismachine.info/` is broken on iPadOS - it shows `Mac OS` ‍

Comment: From 15th Jan 2020, The new microsoft Edge is based on Chromium . Due to which the the user-agent is changed for the edge:
---
`User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.74 Safari/537.36 Edg/79.0.309.43`
---
So need to update the browser array and add `/edg/i` in order to detect new Edge version. As current code returns `Chrome` for the new version.

Comment: By the Following can I get System Name of the clients . Or is any way to get it??

Comment: this script recognizes windows server 10 and windows 10 as the same. is there any way to recognize that the user's operation is a windows 10 server?

Answer (score 10):

When you go to a website, your browser sends a request to the web server including a lot of information. This information might look something like this:

```
GET /questions/18070154/get-operating-system-info-with-php HTTP/1.1  
Host: stackoverflow.com  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 
            (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36 
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8  
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5  
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch  
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7  
Keep-Alive: 300  
Connection: keep-alive  
Cookie: <cookie data removed> 
Pragma: no-cache  
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

These information are all used by the web server to determine how to handle the request; the preferred language and whether compression is allowed.

In PHP, all this information is stored in the `$_SERVER` array. To see what you're sending to a web server, create a new PHP file and print out everything from the array.

```
<pre><?php print_r($_SERVER); ?></pre>
```

This will give you a nice representation of everything that's being sent to the server, from where you can extract the desired information, e.g. `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to get the operating system and browser.

Comment: To make this more readable, I usually do echo "<PRE>"; print_r($_SERVER); echo "</PRE>"; This is personal preference but it helps me read big arrays, and this IS a big array.

Comment: @smcjones: you'd better do: echo '<pre>'.print_r($_SERVER, true).'</pre>';

it is cleaner like that :)

Answer (score 7):

Took the following code from php manual for [get_browser](http://php.net/get_browser).

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
```

The `$browser` array has `platform` information included which gives  you the specific Operating System in use.

Please make sure to see the "Notes" section in that page.  This might be something (thismachine.info) is using if not something already pointed in other answers.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18070424/175071) by [Fred-II](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii) I wanted to share my take on the getOS function, it avoids globals, merges both lists and detects the architecture (x32/x64)

```
/**
 * @param $user_agent null
 * @return string
 */
function getOS($user_agent = null)
{
    if(!isset($user_agent) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
        $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    }

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070154/get-operating-system-info-with-php
    $os_array = [
        'windows nt 10'                              =>  'Windows 10',
        'windows nt 6.3'                             =>  'Windows 8.1',
        'windows nt 6.2'                             =>  'Windows 8',
        'windows nt 6.1|windows nt 7.0'              =>  'Windows 7',
        'windows nt 6.0'                             =>  'Windows Vista',
        'windows nt 5.2'                             =>  'Windows Server 2003/XP x64',
        'windows nt 5.1'                             =>  'Windows XP',
        'windows xp'                                 =>  'Windows XP',
        'windows nt 5.0|windows nt5.1|windows 2000'  =>  'Windows 2000',
        'windows me'                                 =>  'Windows ME',
        'windows nt 4.0|winnt4.0'                    =>  'Windows NT',
        'windows ce'                                 =>  'Windows CE',
        'windows 98|win98'                           =>  'Windows 98',
        'windows 95|win95'                           =>  'Windows 95',
        'win16'                                      =>  'Windows 3.11',
        'mac os x 10.1[^0-9]'                        =>  'Mac OS X Puma',
        'macintosh|mac os x'                         =>  'Mac OS X',
        'mac_powerpc'                                =>  'Mac OS 9',
        'ubuntu'                                     =>  'Linux - Ubuntu',
        'iphone'                                     =>  'iPhone',
        'ipod'                                       =>  'iPod',
        'ipad'                                       =>  'iPad',
        'android'                                    =>  'Android',
        'blackberry'                                 =>  'BlackBerry',
        'webos'                                      =>  'Mobile',
        'linux'                                      =>  'Linux',

        '(media center pc).([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2})'=>'Windows Media Center',
        '(win)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9x]{1,2})'=>'Windows',
        '(win)([0-9]{2})'=>'Windows',
        '(windows)([0-9x]{2})'=>'Windows',

        // Doesn't seem like these are necessary...not totally sure though..
        //'(winnt)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}'=>'Windows NT',
        //'(windows nt)(([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1})'=>'Windows NT', // fix by bg

        'Win 9x 4.90'=>'Windows ME',
        '(windows)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2})'=>'Windows',
        'win32'=>'Windows',
        '(java)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2})'=>'Java',
        '(Solaris)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9x]{1,2}){0,1}'=>'Solaris',
        'dos x86'=>'DOS',
        'Mac OS X'=>'Mac OS X',
        'Mac_PowerPC'=>'Macintosh PowerPC',
        '(mac|Macintosh)'=>'Mac OS',
        '(sunos)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}'=>'SunOS',
        '(beos)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}'=>'BeOS',
        '(risc os)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2})'=>'RISC OS',
        'unix'=>'Unix',
        'os/2'=>'OS/2',
        'freebsd'=>'FreeBSD',
        'openbsd'=>'OpenBSD',
        'netbsd'=>'NetBSD',
        'irix'=>'IRIX',
        'plan9'=>'Plan9',
        'osf'=>'OSF',
        'aix'=>'AIX',
        'GNU Hurd'=>'GNU Hurd',
        '(fedora)'=>'Linux - Fedora',
        '(kubuntu)'=>'Linux - Kubuntu',
        '(ubuntu)'=>'Linux - Ubuntu',
        '(debian)'=>'Linux - Debian',
        '(CentOS)'=>'Linux - CentOS',
        '(Mandriva).([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?(\.[0-9]{1,3})?)'=>'Linux - Mandriva',
        '(SUSE).([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?(\.[0-9]{1,3})?)'=>'Linux - SUSE',
        '(Dropline)'=>'Linux - Slackware (Dropline GNOME)',
        '(ASPLinux)'=>'Linux - ASPLinux',
        '(Red Hat)'=>'Linux - Red Hat',
        // Loads of Linux machines will be detected as unix.
        // Actually, all of the linux machines I've checked have the 'X11' in the User Agent.
        //'X11'=>'Unix',
        '(linux)'=>'Linux',
        '(amigaos)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2})'=>'AmigaOS',
        'amiga-aweb'=>'AmigaOS',
        'amiga'=>'Amiga',
        'AvantGo'=>'PalmOS',
        //'(Linux)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}(rel\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}-([0-9]{1,2}) i([0-9]{1})86){1}'=>'Linux',
        //'(Linux)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}(rel\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1} i([0-9]{1}86)){1}'=>'Linux',
        //'(Linux)([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}(rel\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1})'=>'Linux',
        '[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}'=>'Linux',
        '(webtv)/([0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2})'=>'WebTV',
        'Dreamcast'=>'Dreamcast OS',
        'GetRight'=>'Windows',
        'go!zilla'=>'Windows',
        'gozilla'=>'Windows',
        'gulliver'=>'Windows',
        'ia archiver'=>'Windows',
        'NetPositive'=>'Windows',
        'mass downloader'=>'Windows',
        'microsoft'=>'Windows',
        'offline explorer'=>'Windows',
        'teleport'=>'Windows',
        'web downloader'=>'Windows',
        'webcapture'=>'Windows',
        'webcollage'=>'Windows',
        'webcopier'=>'Windows',
        'webstripper'=>'Windows',
        'webzip'=>'Windows',
        'wget'=>'Windows',
        'Java'=>'Unknown',
        'flashget'=>'Windows',

        // delete next line if the script show not the right OS
        //'(PHP)/([0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2})'=>'PHP',
        'MS FrontPage'=>'Windows',
        '(msproxy)/([0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2})'=>'Windows',
        '(msie)([0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2})'=>'Windows',
        'libwww-perl'=>'Unix',
        'UP.Browser'=>'Windows CE',
        'NetAnts'=>'Windows',
    ];

    // https://github.com/ahmad-sa3d/php-useragent/blob/master/core/user_agent.php
    $arch_regex = '/\b(x86_64|x86-64|Win64|WOW64|x64|ia64|amd64|ppc64|sparc64|IRIX64)\b/ix';
    $arch = preg_match($arch_regex, $user_agent) ? '64' : '32';

    foreach ($os_array as $regex => $value) {
        if (preg_match('{\b('.$regex.')\b}i', $user_agent)) {
            return $value.' x'.$arch;
        }
    }

    return 'Unknown';
}
```

Comment: The inherent problem with this approach is that the list has to be maintained to add new technologies

Comment: tried editing, but it wont let me make a single character change, so:
`'[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3})' => 'Linux',`
should be
`'[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,3}' => 'Linux',`

Comment: @MonOve Fix added

Comment: I moved 'Linux' line under all mobiles OS (in first part of the list, just after 'webos'), because, if not, my smartphone was recognized as 'Linux' OS instead of 'Android' .

Comment: @Meloman add that change as a suggested edit and I'll approve it

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get all those information, you might want to read this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

You can run the sample code and you'll see how it works:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

The above example will output something similar to:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7) Gecko/20040803 Firefox/0.9.3

Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5\.1; .*rv:.*) gecko/.* firefox/0\.9.*$
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/0.9*
    [parent] => Firefox 0.9
    [platform] => WinXP
    [browser] => Firefox
    [version] => 0.9
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 9
    [cssversion] => 2
    [frames] => 1
    [iframes] => 1
    [tables] => 1
    [cookies] => 1
    [backgroundsounds] =>
    [vbscript] =>
    [javascript] => 1
    [javaapplets] => 1
    [activexcontrols] =>
    [cdf] =>
    [aol] =>
    [beta] => 1
    [win16] =>
    [crawler] =>
    [stripper] =>
    [wap] =>
    [netclr] =>
)
```

Comment: I was trying to fix the syntax highlighting in your answer, but you rejected the edit...

Comment: I purposely wanted just the [browser_name_regex] and [browser_name_pattern] highlighted otherwise you have not done anything wrong. Okay?

Answer (score 2):

If you want very few info like a class in your html for common browsers for instance, you could use:

```
function get_browser()
{
    $browser = '';
    $ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    if (preg_match('~(?:msie ?|trident.+?; ?rv: ?)(\d+)~', $ua, $matches)) $browser = 'ie ie'.$matches[1];
    elseif (preg_match('~(safari|chrome|firefox)~', $ua, $matches)) $browser = $matches[1];

    return $browser;
}
```

which will return 'safari' or 'firefox' or 'chrome', or 'ie ie8', 'ie ie9', 'ie ie10', 'ie ie11'.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for this information in `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`, but its format is free-form, not guaranteed to be sent, and could easily be altered by the user, whether for privacy or other reasons.

If you've not set the `browsecap` directive, this will return a warning. To make sure it's set, you can retrieve the value using `ini_get` and see if it's set.

```
if(ini_get("browscap")) {
    $browser = get_browser(null, true);
    $browser = get_browser($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);  
}
```

As *kba* explained in his answer, your browser sends a lot of information to the server while loading a webpage. Most websites use these [User-agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) information to determine the visitor's operating system, browser and various information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a LAN (Local Area Network) with an Active Directory Domain Controller you can use shell_exec() method to execute commands like:

```
wmic /node:192.168.1.3 computersystem get /format:List
```

to get the system information and process the result