# php system info for windows

Tags: php, windows, system

Well, the script I found to get the system info via php is

[biobeo.com/sys.txt](http://biobeo.com/sys.txt)

I have also attatched the screen shot.

[image]

I can get the linux hosted system info from this, but what if I am using Windows?

My system is Windows 8.1 64bit Application I am using is Xampp 1.8

Any one here can please tell me the solution for this?

Comment: No solution? how's that possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070154/get-operating-system-info-with-php

Comment: that was not the answer for this question !