# I want to get system info in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, windows, wampserver

Is there  any specific function or we have to use some third party script if find suitable script for php system info

Comment: What "system info" are you wanting to get? Number of cores in the processor? Current CPU/memory usage? Operating system version? IP Addresses? It's a pretty vague question that's unlikely to get precise, detailed answers unless you provide more detail

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get operating system info with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070154/get-operating-system-info-with-php)

Comment: [Related search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=system+info+php).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `phpinfo();` for all the information.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

For info in mysql see this guide:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html

Comment: @yamatri-reddy Dont forget to set make click the tick to make it easy on other people to see the answer.