# get exact os detail using codeigniter useragents

Tags: php, codeigniter, operating-system, user-agent

I want to get exact info of which os user is login for this I am using codeigniter useragent library

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');
echo $this->agent->platform(); die;
```

but it shows me **Unknown Windows OS** when I login using window is there any other way to get exact operating system

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070154/get-operating-system-info-with-php

Comment: Client environment detection is not reliable and often leads to false assumptions or missing information. This is due to the fact that it is based on insecure information. Insecure because it is under the sole control of the client, so can be filtered or manipulated at will.

Answer (score 2):

Pleas try using this function,

```
echo php_uname();
echo PHP_OS;
```

since codeigniter is written in php, this will work, you can also refer to the php doc here http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php

Hope this will help

Comment: it will provide the server os information not client machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to get client agent in `PHP`, `User_Agent` is one information in `HTTP REQUEST HEAD` so every client accessing your server will send this information to your server, but it not reliable and can be faked.

Answer (score 0):

$this->load->library('user_agent');

if ($this->agent->is_browser()){

```
$agent = $this->agent->browser().' '.$this->agent->version();
```

}
elseif ($this->agent->is_robot()){

```
$agent = $this->agent->robot();
```

}
elseif ($this->agent->is_mobile()){

```
$agent = $this->agent->mobile();
```

}
else{

```
$agent = 'Unidentified User Agent';
```

}

echo $agent;

echo $this->agent->platform();

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so. Also, see [Formatting Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).