# Open page using different code for iOS and Android in WordPress

Tags: php, android, ios, iphone, wordpress

I am new as a WordPress developer. I have built one website with WordPress,
now I have a problem that I want to open 2 different pages for Android and iOS devices.

I have searched around but did not found what was i looking for..

like:

```
if iOS then

  this code

if Android

  this second code
```

Is that possible in PHP? If yes then how?

I also have Android and iOS apps, and I want to open app direct into App Store or Play Store, like when users for both devices click on the link they will redirect to my app in the Play Store or App Store using detection of iOS and Android.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your question. You say that you searched but did not find anything. You could improve your question by showing what you _did_ find, and explaining why it didn't help. You can [edit] such information into your question. If we understand _why_ the advice on the net didn't work, we can help you better. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this answer: [Get operating system info with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070154/get-operating-system-info-with-php). You should be able to extract the information you need from this to determine whether a user is viewing your webpage on an Android or iOS device, as well as the various other operating systems on the market.