# How to overlap a svg with an including text element consistenly on windows and mac

Tags: css, html, svg, cross-browser, margin

I've got 3 problems coming together and they're driving me crazy.

1: Heading title within a box (max-width:1030px) should resize if the windows gets smaller. The outer borders of this title should always be on the outer borders of the surrounding box.

2: the menu below should overlap (visually cut of) the title a bit (margin-top:-1.5% or something like 30px).
Problem: this works only until the window gets smaller than 900px wide.
Below this value the menu seems to overlap to much on all browsers.

The biggest Problem:
3: I managed it once on firefox and chrome on windows, but! on a mac chrome and safari looks different. firefox is doing the same like on windows.
So i was searching for another way but I didn't managed it.

Problem 1: manage responsive Heading scaling on window size -> svg with an text-element inside. solved!? The size of a SVG is obviously different on a mac than on windows.

Problem 2: negative margin with some responsiveness?

Problem 3: Is it possible to manage this on both OS? 
There is always one browser who is not working like the others and its getting me crazy.

I've added bright background-colors to the boxes to get a better feeling what's happening there. Please visit:

https://benhuebsch.de/wordpress

Problem 1: on Safari the svg text is a bit bigger than 1030px on all browser on both os.

Problem 2: I think my version is the wrong way, but I don't know how to manage this.

Problem 3: Maybe it's just impossible to achieve the same look across browsers.

Do you have some ideas?

Best,
E-G

Comment: For now, the best browser is firefox on both OS. Correct scaling of heading title and negative margin.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem 1: manage responsive Heading scaling on window size -> svg with an text-element 
>   inside. solved!? The size of a SVG is obviously different on a mac than on windows.

If it is the browser you need to know, you can use a variable in PHP

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

You can also use the get_browser() function to check the details of your client's browser like it's version

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
echo $browser['version']; // will echo the client's browser version
```

> Problem 2: negative margin with some responsiveness?

I think CSS media query is the one you're looking for here.

> Problem 3: Is it possible to manage this on both OS? There is always one browser who 
>   is not working like the others and its getting me crazy.

Yes. Just compare the client's browser version.

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
if($browser['version'] <= 1.0){
    // do something
}
```

If you are sure that it's not the browser version then you better off knowing the client's OS from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070154/get-operating-system-info).